# How to open Python file to edit in Visual Studio Code from a terminal?

Tags: command-line, python, visual-studio-code

How can I open python file from the terminal of Ubuntu?

I mean, how can I open it and modify it on Visual Studio Code, instead of running it.

I tried the command:

```bsh
python3 file.py
```

But that just runs the program.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio Code executable is called `code`, simply call it with your python file.

```
code file.py
```

Keep in mind that vscode is meant for managing whole projects, not just a single file.